# Cholesky factorization of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, block-decomposition

Let a Matrix $\mathbf{Y=[A\;b;b^T\;}d]$, where $d$ is a scalar, and $\mathbf{b}$ is a vector.
How to find the cholesky factorization of $\mathbf{Y}$ if i know the cholesky factorization of $\mathbf{A}$.?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! This is called an *update* of the Cholesky factorization; you can find a discussion in many textbooks and papers as well as at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955874/cholesky-factor-when-adding-a-row-and-column-to-already-factorized-matrix.

Comment: @ChristianClason Thanks for the link. Additionally can we update the cholesky factorization of A1=[A a] after a column addition?

Comment: No, because the matrix $A1$ needs to be symmetric and positive definite for a Cholesky factorization to exist, and adding a column without adding a row leads to a non-square matrix which can't be symmetric.

Comment: @ChristianClason Oh! My bad. sorry i intended to ask something else. Anyway i got the answer from the link you sent.